# What is causing certain Primeng icons to change into SVG format and create new tags in the DOM?

Tags: primeng, primeicons

Some of the Primeng icons are having issues where they are being converted to SVG and a similar tag is being created in the DOM. What is causing this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Srd5.png)

What I expect:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kE36H.png)

Comment: You are not using PrimeFaces (JSF / Java Server Faces).

Answer (score 0):

One way is to explicitly disable SVG conversion for these icons by adding the following code to your project:

```
.ui-icon {
  background-image: none !important;
}
```

Another way is to try updating your CSS to target only specific elements and avoid conflicting with the PrimeNG icons. Like modifying specific div or span. example

```
.my-icon-class {
  background-image: url('path/to/icon.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

This code will create a custom icon class that uses an SVG file as the background image. Then add this class to display icon

```
<div class="my-icon-class"></div>
```